# Elastic search logstash http input plugin config error

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Been looking all over the web for a configuration example of the logstash http input plugin configuration, and tried to follow the once I've found. Still running in to problem with the following configuration:

```
input {
   http {
     host => "127.0.0.1"
     post => "31311"
     tags => "wpedit"
   }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {hosts => "localhost:9400"}
}
```

When running `service logstash restart` it responds with `Configuration error. Not restarting. Re-run with configtest parameter for details`.

So I ran a configuration test (`/opt/logstash/bin/logstash --configtest`) and it says everything is fine.

So, my question is, how can I find whats wrong with the configuration? Can you see anything obviously incorrect? I'm fairly new to the world of Elasticsearch, if you could not tell...

Comment: Maybe you meant 'port' instead of 'post'?

Comment: I feel real stupid. That's what happens when you work too many hours in a day. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging